# Matplotlib: Pcolor creates huge images

Tags: python, matplotlib, datagrid

I have a grid with a binary value, and shape `(1000, 60)`, and a line `someLine` of length `(1000,)`.

I'm plotting them as

```
plt.figure()
plt.pcolor(rejectionSpace, cmap=colorMap)
plt.plot(someLine)
plt.xticks(ticks, range(ticks.size))
plt.savefig('myFig.pdf', dpi=5)
plt.close()
```

and yet, the image is of size 15 MB. Why is this so large? And what's the best way of reducing the image size?

Here it is, down-scaled using additional software:

[image: myFig.pdf]

Comment: whats the shape of your `rejectionSpace` array?

Comment: @tom that's the `(1000, 60)`

Comment: Oh,  sorry, completely missed that when I read your question! My answer still stands...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reduce the size of the `pdf` if you rasterize the `pcolor` object.

```
plt.pcolor(rejectionSpace, cmap=colorMap, rasterized=True)
```

Of course, this may reduce the quality of the image. You can change the dpi of the rasterized parts of the figure with the `dpi` option to `savefig`, so you may need to experiment with that to find a balance between file size and a suitable resolution.

A simple test:

```
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: a=np.random.rand(500,500)

In [4]: plt.pcolor(a)

In [5]: plt.savefig('pcolor.pdf')

In [6]: plt.clf()

In [7]: plt.pcolor(a,rasterized=True)

In [7]: plt.savefig('pcolor_r.pdf', dpi=300)

$ ls -lh pcolor*
  5.1M Nov 20 11:46 pcolor.pdf
  994K Nov 20 11:47 pcolor_r.pdf
```

Comment: It's down from 15mb to 15kb. Amazing!

Comment: Didn't reduce for me when generating in .svg format